# How can I get program to display first and last initials as many times as user wants

Tags: c++

THIS WONT WORK it says terminate called
after throwing an instance out of range

char ans;

do{
cout<<"Whats your full name\n";

string fullname;

```
getline(cin,fullname);
char first=fullname[0];
int index=fullname.find(' ');
char last=fullname.at(index+1);

cout<<first<<" "<<last<<endl;
cout<<"wanna do it again? enter y\n";
cin>>ans;
}while(ans=='y');
```

Comment: See the duplicate. On the second iteration of the loop, `fullname` is an empty string.